# How to center a container on Flex?

Tags: css

How to center the .container so that the items on the small screen are left and .container to center.

My example
https://codepen.io/zakhar_coder/pen/QWbQxdE?editors=1100

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 370px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>    
</div>
```

[image: This is how items should look. In the photo, the block itself is not centered]

[this option of placing elements is not suitable for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9HJk.jpg)

Comment: try adding margin-right:auto for the last element .item:last-of-type{margin-right:auto;} or change margin: 0 30px 30px 0; to  margin: 0 auto 30px 0;

Comment: Your image does not show the items centered. You probably want to remove `justify-content: center;`

Comment: How about media queries?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, probably the only option is to do flexible rather than fixed blocks and use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need flex for that. Give a `max-width` to the container and force its width to 100%.  After that you can center it using `margin: 0 auto;`.

If you use `justify-content: center;` it will center only its content, not the container.

Example:

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  /* added code */
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  /* added code */
  max-width: 370px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Click here for the Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/vYOdrWw).

Comment: Thank you. Your version works better, but the small size is also bad works.

Comment: You obviously can adjust the "max-width" to your preferences, I used the 800px as an example.